# Call a function inside a variable and eval

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  pnlTest.addEvent(document.getElementById("dividerImg"), "mousedown", moveEvent = function(){eval(pnlTest.MoveSeparator('right'))}, false);
</script>
```

It runs when you click a button image.

This script is created by the component obout splitter http://www.obout.com/splitter/ex_collapseexpandpanel.aspx. How collapse the panel by clicking the F11?

Comment: You meant button `F11`?

Comment: yes the f11 button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an [Immediately-invoked function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
<script>
    (function() {
        eval(pnlTest.MoveSeparator('right'));
    }());
</script>
```

But please remember that [eval is evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/). You should try to avoid using it.

Comment: OP said he need a key event to to run the handler.

Comment: Rahil Wazir: When I posted my answer, the question looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25203766/1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need `keydown` event. `F11` has key code `122` and also you need to prevent default browser action. Otherwise most browsers binded the `F11` key to fullscreen event.

```
var divider = document.getElementById("dividerImg");
pnlTest.addEvent(divider, "keydown", moveEvent = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 122 && e.keyCode === 122) {
        e.preventDefault();
        eval(pnlTest.MoveSeparator('right'))
    }
}, false);
```